# Get admin path programatically

Tags: admin, admin-panel, administration

Is there any way to get the admin path for a given installation? Most of the time is /admin, but I want to know if there is a certain way to get the path of the admin programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use,

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml")
```

Answer (score 8):

To get the Adminhtml Frontname in Magento local.xml try

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName');
```

From etc/local.xml

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
```